# Why React is rendering parent element, even if changed state isn't used in jsx? (Using React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

Im doing a React small training app using Hooks. Here's the example:
There is a MainPage.js and it has 3 similar child components Card.js. I have global state in MainPage and each Card has its own local state. Every Card has prop "id" from MainPage and clickButton func.

When I click button in any Card there are 2 operations:

1. Local variable 'clicked' becomes true.
2. The function from parent component is invoked and sets value to global state variable 'firstCard'.

Each file contains console.log() for testing. And when I click the button it shows actual global variable  "firstCard", and 3x times false(default value of variable "clicked" in Card).
It means that component MainPage is rendered after clicking button ? And every Card is rendered too with default value of "clicked".

1. Why MainPage componenet  is rendered, after all we dont use variable "firsCard", except console.log()?
2. How to make that after clicking any button, there will be changes in exactly component local state, and in the same time make global state variable "firstCard" changed too, but without render parent component(we dont use in jsx variable "firstCard")

Thanks for your help !

```
import Card from "../Card/Card";

const Main = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [firstCard, setFirstCard] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards([1, 2, 3]);
  }, []);

  const onClickHandler = (id) => {
    setFirstCard(id);
  };

  console.log(firstCard); // Showing corrrect result

  return (
    <div>
      {cards.map((card, i) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={Date.now() + i}
            id={card}
            clickButton={(id) => onClickHandler(id)}
          ></Card>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Card = ({ id, clickButton }) => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);


  const onClickHandler = () => {
    setClicked(true);
    clickButton(id);
  };

  console.log(clicked); // 3x false

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Card number {id}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => onClickHandler()}> Set ID</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Comment: you look like you are eager to learn. I will point you to React.memo https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: Using the setter function from `useState` is what causes the re-render. Since you're changing the state variable, the component re-renders so that the changes could be (potentially) reflected in UI.

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong idea how react works.

When you change something in state that component will re render, regardless if you use that state variable in render or not.
Moreover, react will also re render all children of this  component recursively.

Now you can prevent the children from re rendering (not the actual component where state update happened though) in some cases, for that you can look into `React.memo`.

That said prior to React hooks there was a method [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) which you could have used to skip render depending on change in state or props.

Comment: This is the right answer. This is a common misconception that many people new to react have. React is not optimizing by not calling "render", it optimizes by comparing two different results of "render" and only changing the dif in the DOM.

Comment: @giggo1604 yes, sounds true.